# Como abrir explorador de windows con VBA en W10

Tags: vba

Buenos días a todos,

En primer lugar, soy nuevo en stackoverflow y, pese a que ya he estado indagando por distintos hilos, no he conseguido dar con una solución. Para poneros un poquito en situación, estoy desarrollando una aplicación desde el software Movicon de Progea (desarrollo de SCADAs) para mi empresa en Windows 10.

**LA PREGUNTA**: El asunto es que en uno de los sinópticos, tengo un botón 'Examinar' para ejecutar un script en VBA que deberá abrirme un explorador de windows y extraer la ruta de un archivo .txt que yo seleccione. Podríais decirme que método (un pequeño ejemplo también lo agradeceré a muerte) podría utilizar, por favor?

Como info adicional, ya he probado los siguientes métodos:

- Application.FileDialog: esto me abre un explorador pero entiendo que esta pensado para funcionar desde una script de Office, ya que me abre Access cuando se ejecuta la script.
- MSComDlg.CommonDialog: pese a que después de añadir la librería del 'MSComDlg', no he encontrado la extensión 'CommonDialog'... por lo visto, el 'CommonDialog' no está disponible en W10.
- Shell.Application: no ha habido manera que me detecte automáticamente nada después de escribir 'Shell.' por lo que entiendo que no lo tengo disponible por el motivo que sea. Comentar que he incluido la tira de librerías a mi script.

En fin, espero que alguno de vosotros pueda echarme un cable con este asuntillo y disculpar si he dicho alguna barbaridad pero llevo muy poquito en esto de la programación.

Saludos[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIbWB.jpg)

Comment: `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` y elegir cualquier tipo de extensión te sirve?

Comment: Este es el fragmento de código que utilicé Flowen:

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).AllowMultiSelect = False
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Title = "Select a file"
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).InitialFileName = "C:\"
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Show

A que te refieres con elegir un tipo de extensión?

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres conseguir. Con FileDialog puedes buscar ficheros en el explorador de archivos. No te sirve con seleccionar el mencionado .txt?

Comment: Mira este articulo a ver si te sirve para seleccionar archivos solo con extensión txt....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856592/file-selector-how-do-i-specify-filetype

Comment: Puesto que el link que me ha puesto rsanfer también va relacionado con 'FileDialog' creo que os respondo a los 2, puede que no me haya explicado del todo bien en el post.

El asunto es que desarrollo desde un software que no tiene nada que ver con Office. Utilizado el método FileDialog, lo que ocurre es que en primer lugar se me abre MsAccess al cual se le superpone el explorador de archivos. Si desarrollase mi aplicación desde Office, me iría perfecto pero no en mi caso, al ser una aplicación con fines comerciales, no queda muy bien abrir Access cuando solo necesito la ruta de un txt.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda chicos! ;)